# Obter o nome de um atributo de um objeto

Tags: delphi

Tenho a seguinte classe

```
TLog = class
private
  FDescricao: string;
  FCodigo: Integer;
public
  property Codigo: Integer read FCodigo write FCodigo;
  property Descricao: string read FDescricao write FDescricao;
end;
```

Eu quero criar um método que obtenha o nome do atributo (do objeto instanciado) em String. Exemplo:

```
ConverEmString(Log.Codigo) = "Codigo"
ConverEmString(Log.Descricao) = "Descrição"
```

É possível fazer isso? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o RTTI do delphi. Se for alguma versão posterior a 2010 pode-se utilizar o RTTI novo. Mas vou dar o exemplo com o antigo que funciona em todos desde a versão 5

```
var
  oPropList: TPropList;
begin
  GetPropList(seuObjeto.ClassInfo, tkProperties, @oPropList);
```

Utilizando o método GetPropList, que retorna a lista de Properties **published** do objeto, no terceiro parâmetro @PropList (é usado o @ porque o parâmetro esperado é do tipo PPropList que é um ponteiro para TPropList).

Essa lista é um array de tamanho fixo, por isso, ao percorrer o array, a cada interação é necessário checkar se o valor do item do array está nil e se esiver, dar um break e encerrar o laço:

```
  for I := Low(oPropList) to High(oPropList) do
  begin
    if not Assigned(oPropList[I]) then
      Break;

    ShowMessage(oPropList[I]^.Name);
  end;
```

Cada item do Array é uma PropInfo, que possui informações da property, como tipo, nome, métodos Get e Set, Valores default, índice, etc.
Observacao: O Objeto PropInfo possui apenas as informações da property, e não seu valor em alguma instância da classe.

```
  TPropInfo = packed record
    PropType: PPTypeInfo;
    GetProc: Pointer;
    SetProc: Pointer;
    StoredProc: Pointer;
    Index: Integer;
    Default: Longint;
    NameIndex: SmallInt;
    Name: ShortString;
  end;
```

De posse destes dados e dos métodos citados citado abaixo, podemos obter todos os dados published do Objeto

```
  label.caption = oPropList[I]^.name;
  case oPropList[I]^.PropType^.Kind of
    tkString, tkWChar, tkLString, tkWString, tkChar: Label.Caption :=
        Label.Caption + ' : ' + GetStrProp(seuObjeto, oPropList[I]);
    tkInteger: Label.Caption :=
        Label.Caption + ' : ' + IntToStr(GetOrdProp(seuObjeto, oPropList[I]));
    tkClass: ;
  end;
```

Note que a checagem pelo tipo nos permite escolher qual método vamos utilizar para obter o valor da property, com os métodos específicos para cada tipo de property.

Os tipos esperados em PropType são:

```
tkUnknown
tkInteger
tkChar
tkEnumeration
tkFloat,
tkString
tkSet
tkClass
tkMethod
tkWChar
tkLString
tkWString,
tkVariant
tkArray
tkRecord
tkInterface
tkInt64
tkDynArray
```

Os métodos de Get e Set das properties são baseados em seus tipos, e podem receber por parâmetro o nome da property ou então um PPropInfo, como foi feito neste exemplo. Os métodos de acordo com os tipos que podem ser utilizado para obter os valores são:

```
GetOrdProp (Inteiros)
GetEnumProp (Tipos enumerados)
GetSetProp (_Sets)
GetObjectProp (Objetos)
GetStrProp (Strings)
GetFloatProp (Pontos Flutuantes)
GetVariantProp (Variant)
GetMethodProp (Métodos)
GetInt64Prop (Inteiros de 64 bits)
```

> Obs: Os atributos para serem obtidos devem ter visibilidade Published

Comment: Legal, muito bem explicado sobre Rtti. Estou utilizando em algumas partes do projeto.
Porém não respondeu o que perguntei! Listar eu consigo, a questão é como obter o nome do atributo (do objeto instanciado) em String > Log.Descrição = "Descrição".
Eu já sei qual atributo eu quero, porém preciso que pegue o nome dele em String. Entendeu?

Comment: Estou usando o Aurelius ORM. Nele preciso passar o nome do campo em string para fazer consultas Where. Estou querendo evitar usar string direto pois, caso venha fazer manutenção e remover o campo/atributo da classe, usando string, só vou descobrir possiveis erros quando executar o sistema. Já usando o "Log.Codigo" caso remova o campo Codigo, já daria erro na compilação, permitindo saber exatamente os locais que estão usando esse campo. Entendeu?

Comment: Qual versão do delphi? Me veio a mente uma ideia com ClassHelpers para tipos básicos

Comment: Utilizar Attributes é uma opção? se for daí dá de resolver fácil

Comment: Como assim Attributes? Pode me dar um exemplo?